# dual stack IPv6 in6addr_loopback vs in6addr_any

Tags: c++, c, linux, ipv6, ipv4

I have a dual stack set on my Linux host and trying to connect to a TCP/IPv6 server that can listen to `in6addr_loopback` or `in6addr_any`, here is a very minimal example of the server :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        exit(1);

    struct sockaddr_in6 serv6;
    memset(&serv6, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));

    int fd6 = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    int loopback = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (loopback)
        serv6.sin6_addr = in6addr_loopback;
    else 
        serv6.sin6_addr= in6addr_any;

    serv6.sin6_port = htons(3000);
    serv6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;

    int opt = 1;
    setsockopt(fd6, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(int));

    if (bind(fd6, (struct sockaddr *)&serv6, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)) < 0) {

        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(fd6, 5);

    int cli = accept(fd6, NULL, NULL);

    char buf[10] = {0};
    int n = read(cli, buf, 9);

    if (n > 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "received %d bytes : %s from ipv6 stack\n", n, buf);
    else
        perror("read");

    exit(0);
}
```

I am using `ncat` on the same host to connect to the server in the following way :

server is listening to `in6addr_any` :

```
ncat 127.0.0.1 3000 // OK
ncat ::1 3000       // OK
ncat ::ffff:127.0.0.1 3000 // OK
```

server is listening to `in6addr_loopback`:

```
ncat 127.0.0.1 3000 // Ncat: Connection refused.
ncat ::1 3000       // OK
ncat ::ffff:127.0.0.1 3000 // Ncat: Connection refused.
```

Why does it work only with an IPv6 address for the loopback interface ?
Thank you.

Comment: `in6addr_loopback` is `::1`.  I seem to remember reading somewhere that this is *not* the same as `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: IPv4-Mapped IPv6 addresses, such as `::ffff:127.0.0.1`, are not actually IPv6 addresses; they are IPv4 addresses that are formatted as IPv6 addresses for the purpose of storing both IP addresses in a common format. They are not allowed to be used as source or destination addresses in IP packets.

Answer (score 2):

To accept both IPv4 and IPv6 clients on a dual-stack listening socket, you should explicitly disable the `IPV6_V6ONLY` option via `setsockopt()` before `bind()`'ing the socket.

But, more importantly, a dual-stack socket bound to `in6addr_any` (`::0`) will bind to **all** local IPv4 **and** IPv6 interfaces, whereas a dual-stack socket bound to `in6addr_loopback` (`::1`) will only be able to bind to an IPv6 loopback interface but not to the IPv4 loopback interface (ie, `::1` != `127.0.0.1`).

Comment: Thank you but `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only` returns 0 on my host, so i guess the socket option is not needed and i expected that all dual-stack listening sockets should accept IPv4 mapped IPv6 addresses, as is it the case with the in6addr_any.

Comment: @Fryz I would do what Remy suggests anyway.  What have you got to lose? - it's two lines of code and it might prevent an obscure bug at some point in the future, when you have forgotten this conversation.

Comment: @PaulSanders You are right, it makes the code more portable.

Comment: @Fryz Since `bindv6only` is configurable, you should not rely on the default config and just set it explicitly to be sure.